# How do I obtain correct confidence intervals for meta-regression of the c-statistic using Metafor (R)

Tags: r, validation, logistic-regression, mixed-models, auc

I am performing internal-external validation, whereby I hold out one study centre in turn, to evaluate the performance of a logistic regression model trained on the other 6 centres. The study contains three time points, so the above process is repeated to train separate models for each of the three time-points.

The logistic regression models were fit using glm, and the AUC and variance of AUC using pROC:
`Collated_Results[16,3] <- var(GST_roc_1, method = "bootstrap", boot.n = 1000)`

I have the following summary table (Collated_Results, cut short for example):

| Centre | Timepoint | AUC | Variance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.73 | 0.016 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.85 | 0.004 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.78 | 0.0056 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.69 | 0.0028 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.77 | 0.003 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.96 | 0.0016 |

Using the Metafor pacakage rma.mv function, I fit a mixed-effects model meta-regression, with random effects for study-timepoint nested within study centre:

```
full.model <- rma.mv(yi = AUC, 
                     V = Variance, 
                     slab = Centre,
                     data = Collated_Results,
                     random = ~ 1 |Centre/Timepoint , 
                     test = "knha", 
                     method = "REML", dfs='contain')
```

The model fits correctly and gives a pooled estimate AUC as follows:

Model Results:

estimate      se     tval  df    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub
0.8507  0.0270  31.4587   5  <.0001  0.7812  0.9202  ***

The problem is that when I call forest(full.model), the 95% confidence intervals for some time-points are over 1 (eg. 1.03), which does not make sense for the AUC metric.

I have tried using the valmeta package which is specifically designed for AUC meta-regression, and the issue doesn't occur there. However, that package doesn't allow the more complex multi-level random effects.

Is anyone aware of how to use rma.mv correctly for the AUC, providing confidence intervals that make sense for this metric?

Thank you in advance,

Ben.